# Eloquent how to do something when delete or update operate on a special model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

Most of my db table contain `create_user_id` and `update_user_id`

How can l update this two field automatic when l use `save()`, `update()`, `insert()`, `createOrUpdate()` and etc method.

For example, l execute this script:

```
$model = Model::find(1);
$model->model_f = 'update';
$model->save();
```

then this record's `model_f` updated, and `update_user_id` updated, too.

l know eloquent can manage `update_time` automatic and l have use it already. But l want to do something else when update or insert or delete

PS: l have a constant named `USERID` to remember current user's id

Answer (score 7):

You could make use of [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers). 
You can hook to the following events on your Model:

```
retrieved  
creating
created
updating
updated
saving
saved
deleting
deleted
restoring
restored
```

Let me give you an example where we are trying to hook into the events emitted by the `App/User` model. You can change this to match your particular Model later on.

To create an observer, run the following command:

```
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User
```

Then you can hook to specific events in your observer.

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\User;

class UserObserver
{

    /**
    * Handle the User "saved" event.
    *
    * @param  \App\User  $user
    * @return void
    */
    public function saved(User $user)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
    * Handle the User "created" event.
    *
    * @param  \App\User  $user
    * @return void
    */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
    * Handle the User "updated" event.
    *
    * @param  \App\User  $user
    * @return void
    */
    public function updated(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Since, in your particular case, you want to hook into these 3 events, you can define the events above and perform additional operations to your model when those events are called.

Don't forget to register this observer in your `AppServiceProvider`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use App\Observers\UserObserver;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class);
    }

    /**
    * Register the service provider.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is pretty simple way to automatically update the `create_user_id` and  `update_user_id`

```
Step1:
```

Open you app folder and create the new file named as `UserStampsTrait.php`

```
Step:2
```

and paste the following code

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;    
trait UserStampsTrait
{
 public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();
    // first we tell the model what to do on a creating event
    static::creating(function($modelName='')
    {
       $createdByColumnName = 'create_user_id ';
      $modelName->$createdByColumnName = Auth::id();
    });

    // // then we tell the model what to do on an updating event
    static::updating(function($modelName='')
    {
      $updatedByColumnName = 'update_user_id';
      $modelName->$updatedByColumnName = Auth::id();
    });    
  }
}
```

Thats it

```
Step:3
```

Open you model which needs to updated the corresponding models automatically

for Example it may be `Post`

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\UserStampsTrait;
class Post extends Model
{
    use UserStampsTrait;
}
```

Thats it